# Stored procedure invocation with VARBINARY(MAX) parameters fails with strange error message?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, ado.net, varbinary

I am trying to store encrypted data into my database (run by MS SQL 2005 Express) using stored procedure.

The stored procedure has the following signature:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveData]
    @FileName AS NVARCHAR(255),
    @Data As VARBINARY(MAX),
    @Key AS VARBINARY(MAX) = NULL,
    @Final AS BIT = NULL
AS
....
```

In my code I have two variables of type `byte[]` with my data:

```
        public byte[] EncryptedData { get; set; }
        public byte[] EncryptedPassword { get; set; }

        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveData", conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, EncryptedData.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, (SqlBinary) EncryptedData));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Key", SqlDbType.VarBinary, EncryptedPassword.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, (SqlBinary)EncryptedPassword)); 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Final", true);
```

Whenever I try to call `ExecuteNonQuery()` I get the following error message (sorry for German, I just wanted to provide the original text, I also provide translation below!):

> Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von '¿'.
>   Bezeichner (beginnend mit '*è
>   ¯äÅõ42‹áºªž(±Z¦ññú>¬ÕÕ]¥Qî)ÀÍE5 Fäø+ïµ1˜Z}»[–A[Åñ#­šužÿÄ}µ} 
>   %ãVð>TÛ¨¡ªƒ·g·SWFW

Here is the English translation of the error message (done by me, so it might and will deviate from the canonic original error message):

> Syntax error near '¿'.
>   Identifier (beginning with '*è
>   ¯äÅõ42‹áºªž(±Z¦ññú>¬ÕÕ]¥Qî)ÀÍE5 Fäø+ïµ1˜Z}»[–A[Åñ#­šužÿÄ}µ} 
>   %ãVð>TÛ¨¡ªƒ·g·SWFW

It seems as if the SQL string is parsed incorectly and some binary data is parsed as an identifier name.

I tried many different approaches here using `.AddWithValue()` and setting parameter properties one by one -- this doesn't help.

Any suggesions?

Comment: What does the stored procedure look like? Does it use dynamic SQL? If you comment out all code from the stored procedure do you still see the error?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, we use just mere concatenation of strings :(( How can we implement it the right way?

Comment: Look into using `sp_executesql` then you can still use parameters for most of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was already pointed out in the comments, so I just answer the question here.

The problem was in using dynamic SQL (the concatenation of SQL strings) in the stored procedure, here is an example:

```
select @sql = 'insert into dbo.DMSFileData ('
    ...
select @sql = @sql + ') VALUES ('
select @sql = @sql + '''' + @FileName + ''''
select @sql = @sql + '''' + convert(varchar(max), @Data) + ''''
```

The correct solution here is to use parameters in concatenation:

```
select @sql = @sql + ', @filename'
select @sql = @sql + ', @filedata'
```

And then execute SQL using `sp_executesql`:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, @params, @ForeignKey, @FileName, @Data
```